# MySQL Replacing Unions with Join to Use Indexing Better

Tags: mysql

I am dealing with three tables (4 GB, 2GB, and 700 MB respectively). I am trying to find out what is the best strategy to index to get a better performance.

The tables looks like the following

Posts: PostID (String, Unique, indexed), OwnerID, Time

Likes: Post_ID, UserID (Composite primary key Indexed with Post_Id being first column in Index)

Comments: CommentID (Primary Key), Post_ID (indexed), UserID

The logic is that for every post any number of users can like it and any number can comment on it. While a person can like a post only once, they can comment multiple times.

I want to find out user engagement for each user. That is, I want to know how many likes and how many comments were made by a person for a particular owner. An owner is the owner of that item/post on which people can like or comment.

```
    select distinct userid as cnt from 
    (
        (select userid from likes, posts where post_id=postid and 
                           owner in ('123','456') group by userid)  
        UNION ALL 

        (select userid from comments, posts where post_id=postid 
                           and owner in ('123','456') group by userid)
    ) as data
```

Is this the best way to do it? Can I do better than this? If I wanted to replace union all with join how to go about it and would that make it any better? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct userid) as count from 
(
    (select userid from likes, posts where post_id=postid and 
                       owner in ('123','456') group by userid)  
    UNION ALL 

    (select userid from comments, posts where post_id=postid 
                       and owner in ('123','456') group by userid)
) as data
```

could try...

You won't need group by since there are no aggregations, and the Distinct takes out duplicates.

```
SELECT count(distinct a.userid) as cnt from likes a 
full outer join posts b on a.userid = b.userid 
full outer join comments c on a.userid = c.userid 
WHERE a.owner in ('123','456') and c.owner in ('123','456') and b.post_Id = postid
```

it's not clear whether you just call the distinct userid cnt or you actually want a count if the latter you would do a `count(distinct userid)` as cnt

in some cases union all would be faster, but in this case, userid should have an index on it, which would make it faster than your original query. it depends on how well written your join query is..

Some reasons it may be faster.

- it uses more lightweight statistics collection model (based on
  cardinality, rather than random dives)
     query will get parsed only once (no need for multiple subselect evaluation)
     resultset will not be materialized in a temptable (it gets even for UNION ALL)

Please read this article on which one you should use. Join or Union

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111113150620AA81oQI

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I need count(distinct userid). You are right I don't need the group by. The owner is part of posts table though. Also, posts and likes join on PostID and post_id column. Same with comments table. But I am tempted to try this. Could you explain (pun ?) why this would be better than union all?

Comment: Thanks again. Two things 1) it is MySQL so we don't really have Full outer join. Also, 2) a and b should join on post_id. Same with b and c. I am asking because I am not clear if I explained the question correctly. Also, did you mean a.userid = c.userid? What if a user likes a post but does not comment on it? I guess that is why you meant full outer join to take either. But given that we don't have full outer join how do we simulate it?

Comment: haha the replacement for mysql is a union. You got it already! I did mean a.userid=c.userid. Correct, that's the use of the full outer join. Forgot mysql didnt do that, been workin on sql-server lately.

Comment: Lol ok. So is this the only way of doing it?